# Keeping notifications in panel until user taps them

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I've noticed that when a user receives a push notification, if he taps it from the notification panel (or manually launches the app, for that matter), it'll remove the notification from the panel. I suppose this is fine if it's a single notification, but what about if the user has multiple notifications? I wouldn't want it to clear all of them, just the one that was tapped.

I've been having trouble finding out information on this. I know it MUST be possible, because the Skype app does it. You receive 5 push notifications about unread messages on Skype, and if you tap one, it launches the app. However, it doesn't remove all the notifications from the panel, only the one you tapped. How are they doing this?

Comment: Its not possible for an app to delete an individual notification from the notification center. The OS is automatically deleting the notification from NC when its tapped on (note it didn't used to do that, this is recent behavior with the OS).

Comment: @MartinH how is Skype doing it then? I'm iOS 8.4.1 and just tested it with Skype. I had 5 chat notifications, tapped one, it opened Skype, and when I checked the notifications pane there were now 4. Tapped another, then there were 3.

Comment: I would guess that Skype is using local notifications and only clearing the ones that corresponds to messages the user has read

Comment: Like I say, the OS is doing it. I can get exactly the same behavior as you just described with my app, I just ran it on 8.1.3 and had 4 notifications, then tapped one to launch the app, after I went back there were now 3 notifications. But I can assure you my app is not deleting any individual notifications. I'm not sure when the OS started doing it, maybe with OS 8 or 8.1. Previously they wouldn't be deleted like this. This deletion only happens if the user clicks on it from within the notification center, it doesn't happen if clicked on from the home screen